# how to create ssrs report to print result of all student in the same class at once

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I have a table containing student scores in various subject, I have created a report that prints a single student report card. how can I Crete an SSRs report that will print the report of all student in the same class at once. thank you

Comment: I have been able to create the report so that it print for a single student assigning position getting total score, average etc but for the whole class i don't know how to go about it

Answer (score 0):

You first need to setup a stored procedure or SQL statement to get the desired results. After that on your SSRS report use `Tablix` component to print the data in a tabular format (if that is what you want). If you want to print student per page, then add the `Tablix`, remove all the rows and columns, and add a rectangle inside of it. Then place the labels and textboxes in the rectangle.

Comment: Thank you for your response but my problem is have been able to create a report to print the result for a single student in a class assigning position, average, total, number of subjects offered etc but for the whole class i don't know how to go about it. how do i create a stored proceedure to move to the next student idnumber in the class

Comment: Please I want to know how I can move to the next student record to print his own result after printing for the first student, then to the next then to next student until the report card of all students have been printed each student per page. Thank you

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to print all of them in a one-by-one fashion? If there is a specific reason for doing so, then use your current logic to pass the student ID to the store procedure or SQL statement, whatever you are using, and send the request like that. You have not explained in your question how you retrieve the data.